# remove the clickable area near arrows carousel bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, arrows

I use Carousel bootstrap to make slideshow, I only want to click on the exact arrows icon to move slide, but the thing is that it lets you to click everywhere near the arrows (above and below), is there any way that I can adjust it can only be clicked on the arrows. I did the code below to remove that dark area looking shadow already. Thanks

```
 .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
   filter: progid: none !important;
   filter:none !important;
   background-image:none;
   outline: 0;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice in BootStrap's styling for the anchor element that acts as the control the following:

```
.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

The key thing here is `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. Basically, the anchor element stretches from the top of its parent all the way to the bottom (it's `position`ed `absolute`ly).

In addition, it has `width: 15%`.

I would override BS's styling by using a `.parent .child {}` selector, as follows:

```
.yourparentclass .carousel-control {
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 5%;
}
```

This is an example of course - you'll need to do a bit of experimenting but it should lead you down the right track.

You can also target both arrows individually with the following:

```
.yourparentclass .carousel-control.right {}
.yourparentclass .carousel-control.left {}
```

Comment: .carousel-control {top 150px; bottom 150px; width 5%} works like a charm. Thanks so much

Answer (score 7):

Only You have to put top:50%; and bottom:50%; 
and the issue will be solved. :)

**For Bootstrap 3:**

```
#myCarousel .carousel-control{
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

**For Bootstrap 4:**

```
#myCarousel  .carousel-control-prev, 
#myCarousel  .carousel-control-next{
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

and don't forgot to change **#myCarousel** id to your carousal ID or class  selector.